# laravel morphToMany with additional field in pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, many-to-many

I create the following database structure to manage different service contents for different batch and just because this structure must be replicated for sub services too I decided to use a "Many To Many Polymorphic Relations" with Laravel.

[[image: img database structure].](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7a4Cu.png)

To create a new record in table "service_and_relatives_contents" and another association record in table "service____relative_content_batch_a" (my pivot table) I used :

```
$service -> relatives() -> create($arrRelatives)
```

the problem is with that code is that I can't populate "batches_id" fields in my pivot table.
For this reason I used the following code :

```
$relativeId = $service->relatives()->create($arrRelatives)->id;
$service->relatives()->updateExistingPivot($relativeId,['batches_id'=>$keyRelatives]);
```

It works well but it is the right way to create and associate a record in the same time?

Please consider this as an example, I will use laravel conventions for table name and foreign-key for the live version.

Comment: Try '$service->relatives->create($arr)'

Comment: @HasanTıngır it returns error "Method create does not exist."

Comment: @HasanTıngır an alternative could be : 
                $relativeId=$relative->create($arrRelatives)->id;
                $service->relatives()->attach($relativeId,['batches_id'=>$keyRelatives]);

Answer (score 0):

I tink make a create query build morpth and polymorph Many to Many

```
               |-----------------------------------------|
User::join(table_a, user.id, forein.id)->join(table_b, table_a.id, forein.id)
  |----------------------|

> $res = User::join('model_has_roles','users.id','model_id')->join('role_has_permissions','model_has_roles.role_id','model_id')->get()
```

thank